# Color picker for posts and pages

Tags: wp-admin, metabox, color-picker

I want to add color picker to wordpress posts and pages at admin menu. I have this code for color picker:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_color_picker' );
function add_color_picker( $hook ) {

  if( is_admin() ) { 

      // Add the color picker css file       
      wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' ); 

      // Include our custom jQuery file with WordPress Color Picker dependency
      wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-handle', plugins_url( 'custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true ); 
   }
}
```

And js code

```
(function( $ ) {


    // Add Color Picker to all inputs that have 'color-field' class
    $(function() {
        $('.color-field').wpColorPicker();
    });

})( jQuery );
```

my question is how can i use this code to add the metabox with color picker to every admin post or page only?

Comment: just to clarify you want to add the colorpicker in a metabox on the post and page writing/editing screens?

Comment: yes, i want to add it at editing pages

Comment: do have have an existing metabox via `add_meta_box` ?

Comment: no i do not have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution on [Denis Žoljom's post](https://madebydenis.com/adding-metaboxes-to-your-posts-or-pages-color-picker-metabox/)

1) - I have added the `metabox` like this

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mytheme_add_meta_box' );

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_add_meta_box' ) ) {
    function mytheme_add_meta_box(){
        add_meta_box( 'header-page-metabox-options', esc_html__('Header Color', 'mytheme' ), 'mytheme_header_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'low');
    }
}
```

2) - enqueue the color picker style and script

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_backend_scripts');

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_backend_scripts' ) ){
    function mytheme_backend_scripts( $hook ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker');
    }
}
```

3) - create HTML container for the color picker, some description text and the input field

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_header_meta_box' ) ) {
    function mytheme_header_meta_box( $post ) {
        $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
        $header_color = ( isset( $custom['header_color'][0] ) ) ? $custom['header_color'][0] : '';
        wp_nonce_field( 'mytheme_header_meta_box', 'mytheme_header_meta_box_nonce' );
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.color_field').each(function(){
                $(this).wpColorPicker();
                });
        });
        </script>
        <div class="pagebox">
            <p><?php esc_attr_e('Choosse a color for your post header.', 'mytheme' ); ?></p>
            <input class="color_field" type="hidden" name="header_color" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $header_color ); ?>"/>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

4) - save the meta box

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_save_header_meta_box' ) ) {
    function mytheme_save_header_meta_box( $post_id ) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
        }
        if( !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( !isset( $_POST['header_color'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mytheme_header_meta_box_nonce'], 'mytheme_header_meta_box' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $header_color = (isset($_POST['header_color']) && $_POST['header_color']!='') ? $_POST['header_color'] : '';
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'header_color', $header_color);
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'mytheme_save_header_meta_box' );
```

Yeeeeeh ))) Hope this will help someone else ;)