# How to add custom color fields to the category edit page?

Tags: categories, custom-field, css, color-picker

I'm building a Wordpress theme and I am currently finishing the `category.php` page. For this page, I would like the user to select two colors (background color and title/text color) and use them in the `category.php` page.

I searched on the internet for examples on how to do this, but I only found some pieces of code without explanation ([example](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-category-extra-fields/)). I also encountered something about functions for custom fields being deprecated in Wordpress.

Can anyone show me how I add two custom fields for color to each category and how I should apply that in the theme? Or point me to a guide on custom fields in Wordpress?

I don't want to use inline CSS, so I think that we should use `wp_add_inline_styles` to apply the styling. So say that color 1 should be applied to `.background` and color 2 to `.title` for each different category, what would I put in my `wp_add_inline_styles`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom fields and save/update meta data to terms, you basically need to use these action hooks.

**custom fields html for new term**
[{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/)

**save custom field data for new term, get data from $_POST**
[created_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/)

**custom fields html for existing term**
[{$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/)

**save custom field data for existing term, get data from $_POST**
[edited_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/)

**Save / update term meta**
[add_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)
[update_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)

**Get term meta**
[get_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)

You can see the general idea how to use these hooks here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/296767/144392

**Use saved meta data**

One way to use the save term meta data is to get it directly on the category template and add it as inline style to an element.

```
// category.php
$color = sanitize_hex_color(get_term_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'color', true));
<h1<?php echo $color ? ' style="color: ' . $color . ';"' : ''; ?>>Category title</h1>
```

Another way is to add the meta data as inline style with `wp_add_inline_style()` on `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

```
// functions.php
function wpdocs_styles_method() {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $id            = get_queried_object_id();
        $title         = sanitize_hex_color(get_term_meta($id, 'title_color', true));
        $bg            = sanitize_hex_color(get_term_meta($id, 'bg_color', true));
        $custom_css    = '';

        if ( $title ) {
            $custom_css .= ".title {color: {$color};}";
        }
        if ( $bg ) {
            $custom_css .= " .background {background-color: {$bg};}";
        }
        if ( $custom_css ) {
            // update the slug
            wp_add_inline_style( 'your-theme-styles-slug', trim($custom_css) );         
        }
    }    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_styles_method' );
```

**Color picker**

You can use `wpColorPicker` script to turn text input fields into nice color pickers. Usage examples https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/ and [Color picker for posts and pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227539/color-picker-for-posts-and-pages)

Comment: Related articles (I'm not the the author of either of these), https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/ and https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-wordpress-color-picker-api--wp-33067

Comment: Hi Antti, could you provide me with a more concrete example? I’m really a bit clueless how all those functions work together.. Thank you!

Comment: @ralphsmit The linked answer in above and that smashingmagazine article actually demonstrate the taxonomy custom field and saving function usage quite well in my opinion. I would be more or less repeating them.

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Comment: No need to get the term meta data from the archive template as you can use it directly in functions.